# React: How to update object in array map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to update the value of an array when a button is clicked. But I can't figure out how to do so using `this.setState`.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    counters: [{ name: "item1", value: 0 }, { name: "item2", value: 5 }]
  };
  render() {
    return this.state.counters.map((counter, i) => {
      return (
        <div>
          {counter.name}, {counter.value}
          <button onClick={/* increment counter.value here */}>+</button>
        </div>
      );
    });
  }
}
```

How do I increment `counter.value` when the button is clicked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

Since this is the accepted answer now, let me give another optimal method after @Auskennfuchs' comment. Here we use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and `index` to update the current counter. With this method, we are avoiding to use unnecessary `map` over `counters`.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    counters: [{ name: "item1", value: 0 }, { name: "item2", value: 5 }]
  };

  increment = e => {
    const {
      target: {
        dataset: { i }
      }
    } = e;
    const { counters } = this.state;
    const newCounters = Object.assign(counters, {
      ...counters,
      [i]: { ...counters[i], value: counters[i].value + 1 }
    });
    this.setState({ counters: newCounters });
  };

  render() {
    return this.state.counters.map((counter, i) => {
      return (
        <div>
          {counter.name}, {counter.value}
          {/* We are using function reference here */}
          <button data-i={i} onClick={this.increment}>
            +
          </button>
        </div>
      );
    });
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

As an alternative method, you can use `counter` name, map over the `counters` and increment the matched one.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    counters: [{ name: "item1", value: 0 }, { name: "item2", value: 5 }]
  };

  increment = name => {
    const newCounters = this.state.counters.map(counter => {
      // Does not match, so return the counter without changing.
      if (counter.name !== name) return counter;
      // Else (means match) return a new counter but change only the value
      return { ...counter, value: counter.value + 1};
    });

    this.setState({counters: newCounters});
  };


  render() {
    return this.state.counters.map((counter, i) => {
      return (
        <div>
          {counter.name}, {counter.value}
          <button onClick={() => this.increment(counter.name)}>+</button>
        </div>
      );
    });
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

If you use the handler like above it will be recreated on every render. You can either extract it to a separate component or use datasets.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    counters: [{ name: "item1", value: 0 }, { name: "item2", value: 5 }]
  };

  increment = e => {
    const {target} = e;
    const newCounters = this.state.counters.map(counter => {
      if (counter.name !== target.dataset.name) return counter;
      return { ...counter, value: counter.value + 1};
    });
    this.setState({counters: newCounters});
  };


  render() {
    return this.state.counters.map((counter, i) => {
      return (
        <div>
          {counter.name}, {counter.value}
          { /* We are using function reference here */ }
          <button data-name={counter.name} onClick={this.increment}>+</button>
        </div>
      );
    });
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: Although this is the accepted answer, the implementation is not optimal. The second loop through the whole array inside of `increment` isn't needed, because the correct index and counter object can be provided to the function itself.

Comment: @Auskennfuchs, I've added an alternative method after your comment. Yes, mapping is not needed here. But, I would choose Zdenek F's answer if I were the OP. Since extracting the logic is more optimal I think. This is why I upvoted that answer before OP accepted mine.

Answer (score 3):

Consider refactoring the actual counter into its own component. That simplifies the state management as it encapsulates the component responsibility. Suddenly you don't need to update a nested array of objects, but you update just a single state property:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    counters: [{ name: "item1", value: 0 }, { name: "item2", value: 5 }]
  };
  render() {
    return this.state.counters.map((counter, i) => {
      return (
        <Counter name={counter.name} count={counter.value} />
      );
    });
  }
}

class Counter extends React.Component {
  state = {
    count: this.props.count
  }

  increment = () => {
    this.setState({
      count: this.state.count+1
    })
  }

  render() {
      return (
        <div>
          {this.props.name}, {this.state.count}
          <button onClick={this.increment}>+</button>
        </div>
      );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById("root"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `i` that you already have to map the counters to a new array, replacing the target item with an updated count:

```
  () => this.setState(({ counters }) => ({ counters: counters.map((prev, i2) => i === i2 ? { ...counter, count: counter.count + 1 } : prev) }))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a click handler like this

```
handleClick = (index) => {
  this.setState(state => {
    const obj = state.counters[index]; // assign the object at the index to a variable
    obj.value++; // increment the value in the object
    state.counters.splice(index, 1); // remove the object from the array
    return { counters: [...state.counters, obj] };
  });
}
```

Call it like this... `<button onClick={() => handleClick(i)}>`

It's possible to make this shorter. Just wanted to explain how you could go about it

Answer (score 0):

You can have an handler that will map `counters` and update the corresponding counters item of the button clicked. Here we take `i` from the parent scope, and compare it to find the right item to change.

```
<button onClick={() => {
    this.setState(state => ({
        counters: state.counters.map((item, j) => {
            // is this the counter that I want to update?
            if (j === i) {
                return {
                    ...item,
                    value: item.value + 1
                }
            }

            return item
        })
    }))
}}>+</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

With `Array.splice` you can replace an entry inside of an array. This will return a new array with the replaced value:

```
    const {counters}= this.state
    return counters.map((counter, i) => (
        <div key={i}>
          {counter.name}, {counter.value}
          <button onClick={() => this.setState({
               counters: counters.splice(i, 1, {
                   ...counter,
                   value: counter.value+1,
               }
             )})}>+</button>
        </div>
   ));
```

Also it's best practise to give every Fragment inside of a loop it's own unique `key`. And you can get rid of the return, because there's only the return inside of the map function.